# Spring boot repository.save() does not work in test class

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CrimeServiceDBImpl.class, CrimeController.class, Crime.class })
@ComponentScan("com.springmiddleware")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springmiddleware.entities"})
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springmiddleware")
public class TestCrimeServiceDB {


    @Autowired
    private CrimeServiceDBImpl service = new CrimeServiceDBImpl();

    @Test
    public void getAll() {
        try {
            List<Crime> list = this.service.getAllCrimes();
            assertTrue(list.size()!=0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The method `getAllCrimes()` from the service class does just this:

```
@Service
public class CrimeServiceDBImpl implements CrimeService{

    @Autowired
    private CrimeRepository repository;

    private List<Crime> list = new ArrayList<Crime>();



    public CrimeServiceDBImpl() {
        list = UtilityMethods.readFromCSV();
    };


    @Override
    public List<Crime> getAllCrimes() throws IOException {
        repository.saveAll(list);
        return this.repository.findAll();
    }
```

If I call this method when running the application, it correctly add all my objects to the database, but when it's called from the test it doesn't add anything, but no exception is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Which database are you using? Do you mean the data is not persisted in the database after the test has finished? That's because a test always perform a rollback/cleanup when it has finished its work.

Comment: No, I mean that the data does not appear at all. I can just retrieve the data I've added manually. I'm using postgres

Comment: So you mean your `return this.repository.findAll();` doesn't return the data the test inserted by saveAll?

Comment: No, I can retrieve the data that I added by doing manually the query using pgAdmin, I can then do findAll() but if I try to save a new entity using save() or saveAll() they do not appear on database at all

Comment: As i already mentioned that's because a test always perform a rollback/cleanup when it has finished its work. So you never will see any data persisted by a test in the DB!

Comment: But the tests fail for this reason, so how can I resolve that or test differently?

Comment: Did you verify that the list in `saveAll(list)` in the test is not empty?

Comment: Could you please modify your getAllCrimes method in that way that you assign the result of `this.repository.findAll();` to a `List<Crime> result` and return this list? Then you can verify the list before the save (list is not empty) and the result after the retrieval (result is empty?) by debugging.